# Не отображается ImageView в эмуляторе

Tags: java, android, изображения, imageview

[image: в студии отражается картинка,а в эмуляторе нет]
  activity_find_beer.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FindBeerActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:entries="@array/beer_colors"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/find_beer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/color"
        android:layout_below="@+id/color"
        android:text="@string/find_beer"
        android:onClick="onClickFindBeer"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/brands"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/find_beer"
        android:layout_below="@id/find_beer"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/brands" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/brands"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pussy" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

FindBeerActivity.java

```
package com.example.beeradviser3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FindBeerActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedIntanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedIntanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_beer);
    }
    public void onClickFindBeer(View view) {
        TextView brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);
        Spinner color = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.color);
        String beerType = String.valueOf(color.getSelectedItem());
        brands.setText(beerType);
    }


}
```

Comment: В студии отражается картинка, а в эмуляторе нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/pussy"
```

на

```
android:src="@drawable/pussy"
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, картинка появилась! Вот подробнее по этой теме, может кому понадобится: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624554/difference-between-appsrccompat-and-androidsrc-in-androids-layout-xml